# Button not loading activity any suggestions?

Tags: android, runtime-error, onclicklistener, classnotfoundexception

my onclick listener will not run the button I am using, it returns an error and my app closes on my virtual device. I have created the button in the following class and also have it listed in my manifest these are the codes

```
02-15 06:44:07.246: E/AndroidRuntime(837): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-15 06:44:07.246: E/AndroidRuntime(837): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.kingstonrent.uniproject/com.kingstonrent.uniproject.rentcalculator}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.kingstonrent.uniproject.rentcalculator" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.kingstonrent.uniproject-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.kingstonrent.uniproject-2, /system/lib]]
02-15 06:44:07.246: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
02-15 06:44:07.246: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
02-15 06:44:07.246: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-15 06:44:07.246: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
02-15 06:44:07.246: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-15 06:44:07.246: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-15 06:44:07.246: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-15 06:44:07.246: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-15 06:44:07.246: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-15 06:44:07.246: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-15 06:44:07.246: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-15 06:44:07.246: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-15 06:44:07.246: E/AndroidRuntime(837): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.kingstonrent.uniproject.rentcalculator" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.kingstonrent.uniproject-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.kingstonrent.uniproject-2, /system/lib]]
02-15 06:44:07.246: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
02-15 06:44:07.246: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
02-15 06:44:07.246: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
02-15 06:44:07.246: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
02-15 06:44:07.246: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
02-15 06:44:07.246: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  ... 11 more
```

**Manifest**

```
<activity
        android:name="com.kingstonrent.uniproject.rentcalculator"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.kingstonrent.uniproject.RENTCALCULATOR" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**menu.java**

```
    public class menu extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Button sr1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search);
            Button tut2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Notesone);
            Button tut3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.twittertwo);
            Button but4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

            sr1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent ("com.kingstonrent.uniproject.BROWSER"));
            }
        }); 

        tut2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent ("com.kingstonrent.uniproject.MAKENOTE"));
            }
        });

         tut3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent ("com.kingstonrent.uniproject.TWEET"));
            }
        });

         but4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent ("com.kingstonrent.uniproject.RENTCALCULATOR"));

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater awesome = getMenuInflater();
        awesome.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menuone:
        startActivity(new Intent("com.kingstonrent.uniproject.MENUBUTTON"));
        return true;

    }

    return false;
}

}
```

Comment: post edited with log cat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To transit into another screen in Android [Activity].

Explicit Intent

```
  startActivity(new Intent (menu.this,com.kingstonrent.uniproject.BROWSER.class));
```

in which you explicitly mentioning which activity transit to. But for that case you need the context of current activity from which you start the Transit and Class name which you transit to.

In your case

1. Context of Your Current Activity is `menu.this` where you are right now. Please use Naming Convention and Standard appropriately as `menu` is the class. You should use `Menu` instead of `menu`.
2. Transition Acitivity is `com.kingstonrent.uniproject.BROWSER.class` which  should be mentioned by appending `.class` file after the name of your activity.

---

You also need to mentioned the Activity where you Transit to in Yout Manifest file.

```
<application>
<activity
   android:name="com.kingstonrent.uniproject.BROWSER"/>
 <activity
    android:name="com.kingstonrent.uniproject.rentcalculator"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.kingstonrent.uniproject.RENTCALCULATOR" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Way of calling intent class

> Intent instance= new Intent(this, Activity.class);
>
> startActivity(new Intent ("com.kingstonrent.uniproject.BROWSER"));

replace by

> startActivity(new Intent (menu.this,com.kingstonrent.uniproject.BROWSER.class));

same for other declared intent

Comment: I have tried ure suggestion still does not work i changed the other button now that has stopped working aswel any ideas what is happening i am new to eclipse java